# pass data to component in angular after routing

Tags: angular, angular-router

I have found some old answers/methods here on SO on this topic, but I would like to know, that now in 2020 in Angular 9+ what is the best way to pass data to an other component after routing.

The requirements are:

- data shouldn't visible in url bar
- data should be available after page refresh

In my app, I have a simple login component. If login was successfull, it navigates to a component with a child router outlet. I mean, it navigates to `/document/list` and the routing config is like this:

```js
  {
    path: "document", component: StartPageComponent, children: [
      { path: "list", component: DocumentTableComponent }
    ]
  },
```

The `startpage` component looks like this:

```html
<app-header (hamburgerClicked)="onHamburgerClick()" [userName]="userName" [roleName]="roleName"></app-header>
<app-sidebar #appsidebar></app-sidebar>
```

Now, I would like to use in the `StartPageComponent` the values `userName` and `roleName` from the `login` component. What is the best way to do this with the above requirements?

Thanks.

Comment: it's an opinionated question and can't really be answered. but I would start thinking about state management and go forward from there.

Answer (score 0):

You have to store the data in localstorage after authentication in login component.You can use localStorage to retrieve value in component on ngInit lifeCycle method.